# How to equally split the data into second level categories

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have neighbourhoods data: every neighbourhood has its streets and every neighbourhood has its population.

Example data:

Neighbourhoods:

| NeighbourhoodID | Neighbourhood | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Center | 550 |
| 2 | South | 200 |
| 3 | East | 2 |

Streets:

| StreetID | Street | NeighbourhoodID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st | 1 |
| 2 | 2nd | 1 |
| 3 | 3rd | 1 |
| 4 | 4th | 1 |
| 5 | James | 3 |
| 6 | Frank | 3 |
| 7 | Kim | 3 |

Now, I merge neighbourhood data with streets and get:

| Neighbourhood | Street | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Center | 1st | 550 |
| Center | 2nd | 550 |
| Center | 3rd | 550 |
| Center | 4th | 550 |
| East | James | 2 |
| East | Frank | 2 |
| East | Kim | 2 |

Now you can see, that every street has population of neighbourhood population, but not of streets, which is obviously wrong. So my question is how could I equally divide population to streets, so I could get this **wanted result:**

| Neighbourhood | Street | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Center | 1st | 138 |
| Center | 2nd | 138 |
| Center | 3rd | 137 |
| Center | 4th | 137 |
| East | James | 1 |
| East | Frank | 1 |
| East | Kim | 0 |

Comment: What if 1st street houses 300 ppl, 2nd to 4th street only 200/3 each.... what is the logic behind this - why has `East/Kim 0` and not `East/Frank`?  Why have `Center/[1st,2nd] 138` and `Center/[3rd,4th] 137` and not `Center/[1st,2nd,3rd] 138` and `Center/4th 136` ? What did you try to solve it?

Comment: _How_ did you merge this? [mre]? Please [edit] and add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `transform`

```
def split_population(neigh_pop):
    # number of streets in the neighbourhood 
    N = neigh_pop.size
    # divide population evenly 
    street_pop = neigh_pop // N 
    # remaining population 
    remainder = neigh_pop.iloc[0] % N
    # divide the remainder among the first streets 
    street_pop[:remainder] += 1
    return street_pop

>>> df

  Neighbourhood Street  Population
0        Center    1st         550
1        Center    2nd         550
2        Center    3rd         550
3        Center    4th         550
4          East  James           2
5          East  Frank           2
6          East    Kim           2
    
>>> df['Population'] = df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['Population'].transform(split_population)
>>> df

  Neighbourhood Street  Population
0        Center    1st         138
1        Center    2nd         138
2        Center    3rd         137
3        Center    4th         137
4          East  James           1
5          East  Frank           1
6          East    Kim           0
```